# Linear independence and free basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How can I show whether the following vectors form a free basis of $\mathbb Z^3$?

(1,2,2), (-1,0,2), (2,-1,4)

Is a free basis the same as a normal basis and does the method for determining linear independence change when the vector space is $\mathbb Z^3$ rather than $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: Note:  a [vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) must be over a field; are you talking about [modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics))?

Answer (score 1):

I'll just say something about the difference between $\mathbb{Z}^3$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$. This won't answer your question, but maybe helps you get a better view of what an answer would require.

A basis has two properties:

1) Every vector can be written as a linear combination of the basis elements in at least one way

2) Every vector can be written as a linear combination of the basis elements in at most one way

Vectors in the candidate basis being linearly independent is enough to imply 2). This is true both over $\mathbb{Z}$ and over $\mathbb{R}$, with the same not-so-trivial reasoning in both cases.

Also, in both cases it is true that a necessary (but not sufficient!) condition for 1) is that the candidate basis has at least 3 elements. This is completely obvious when you picture the situation geometrically, but perhaps needs a bit of work to obtain from the definitions. However this bit of work is the same in both cases.

Now for an important difference. Over $\mathbb{R}$ we have the **Magic Theorem** that says that when the vectors in the candidate basis are linearly independent, having $3$ of them all of a sudden *is* sufficient to imply 1) (making your candidate basis an actual basis).

If this magic theorem sounds not plausible at all to you then you'll find $\mathbb{Z}^3$ on your side. Look at the set $\{(2, 0, 0), (0, 2, 0), (0, 0, 2)\}$. These are three linearly independent vectors but they do not form a basis of $\mathbb{Z}^3$ since any element of $\mathbb{Z}^3$ with an odd coordinate will not be in the span of this set of three vectors.

Comment: When we consider the span of those three elements you chose, do we only consider integer multiples of them? How can I check whether the vectors above do span $\mathbb Z^3$?

Comment: Yes the span are linear combinations where the scalars come from $\mathbb{Z}$, so sums of integer multiples

Comment: Following my answer: you need to show 1) and 2). For 2) it is sufficient to check linear independence, as your were already planning to do judging from your post. However, as I warn you in the answer, when you have linear independence you do **not** get 1) for free (as you would in the $\mathbb{R}^3$ case). Instead you need to give a separate argument that every vector in $\mathbb{Z}^3$ van be written as an integer linear combination of the basis vectors.

Comment: When checking for linear independence by calculating the rank of the matrix whose columns are the vectors, do I have to worry about row operations that involve fractions? Can I add half of row 1 to row 2 for example? or can I only do integer linear combinations of rows as well? Sorry if sounds stupid

Comment: It depends on the outcome. If you don't worry about fractions you are checking linear independence over $\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{Q}$). If the answer is that YES the vectors are linearly independent over these fields (which I expect to be the case here, given how the question was worded) then it follows automatically that they are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Z}$ too. To see this: think about what it would mean to be linearly *dependent* over $\mathbb{Z}$. Any demonstration of that would immediately show the vectors to be linearly dependent over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ as well

Comment: ...so if you find that such a linearly dependency over $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ can *not* happen you know it cannot happen over $\mathbb{Z}$ either. As we already expect the vectors to be linearly independent, it seems safe to not worry about fractions. On the other hand: if you find that the vectors *are* linearly dependent over $\mathbb{R}$ then we are in a totally different situation. In that case it may not be immediately clear wether or not they are linearly dependent over $\mathbb{Z}$ but it is clear that they cannot form a basis of all of $\mathbb{Z}^3$...

Comment: ...since their $\mathbb{Z}$-span will still be contained in their $\mathbb{R}$-span which is only 1 or 2 dimensional

Comment: Are 4 vectors in $\mathbb Z^3$ necessarily linearly dependent?

Comment: I'm inclined to say yes. But there are two definitions of linear dependence around. The first, that you can write 0 as a non-trivial linear combination of the 4 vectors does indeed hold. But the other one, that one of the vectors must be in the span of the three others does not.

Comment: BTW you do not sound stupid at all. Your questions point straight to the heart of the matter.